# Safe to use StepUp-Converter to power LED-Monitor?

Tags: power-supply, power, boost, monitor

I would like to use the following setup, since I already have the meanwell-powersupply. Can anybody tell me if this should be safe as long as I care for good cooling of the Step-Up-Converter, good and safely soldered connections with quality cables (not just jumper cable)? :

- DC230V (Germany) =>
- Mean Well Powersupply LPV-100-5, 60 W, 5V, 12A =>
- DC/DC-stepup-converter range 4,5-32V convertable to 5-35V with max 4A
  current out =>
- LED-Monitor, 12V, 3A, 36W

I want to parallely power a raspberry pi and a few 5v powered sensors. The StepUp-Converter shall be heatsinked from 20W output on, to I plan to cool this with active, but slow-running 80mm fan and passive heatsinks.
I am thankful for any hints =) ! Best regards, Oliver

Comment: so, how many fans does the average 230 V AC ->12V DC LED screen supply have? (hint: 0) What does that say about energy wasted in your step-up converter? So: frankly, you should go for the usual 230V-12V adapter. makes way more sense than doing two conversions.

Comment: well, you are probably right abou this.. but I should have mentioned, that I dont have the space for 2 power-supplies inside the project-housing. So I have to do either 230V=>12V=>5V or the way I described in the question. Normally I would have done the latter, but I already have a power-supply from 230V to 5V with the desired dimensions regarding capacity etc.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised a 36W step up converter should be any smaller than a 36W step down. Usually, the opposite is the case! Especially considering the proposed heat sink, there's something unlikely about that.

Comment: Could you maybe link to data sheets of the supplies in question?

Comment: 36W step Up converter is smaller than a complete second power supply, thats what I meant. I have a 230V=>5V 12A power supply already and I have 5V powered devices and a 12V-36W(3A) LED-Monitor. I want to put everything in a single housing (MagicMirror Project extended a bit)
The devices are those found here :
[Power-Supply](https://www.amazon.de/Mean-Well-Netzteil-LPV-100-5-12A/dp/B00MWQF6M2)
[Step-Up Converter](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B075JQTPX6)

Comment: a) amazon is not a good source for electronic components. Buy somewhere that gives you data sheets. b) lacking any further documentation: I'm almost certain your step-up converter (which, by the way, is "a complete power supply") will *not* deliver 3 A at 12 V. Have you seen the size of that inductor?! How will you push 36 W through an inductor core of less than 1cm × 1cm? This is badly specified electronics, and if you buy this kind of thing on amazon, you have no one to blame but yourself if it doesn't fullfill its specs.

Comment: furthermore: definitely not even a step-up converter: "2. Die Eingangsspannung muss mindestens 1V höher als die Ausgangsspannung sein." (Engl.: "2. the input voltage must be at least 1V higher than the output voltage"). I'm pretty sure that 5 V < 12 V + 1V... Please, for your own sanity, don't buy stuff from people who can't even label the devices they're selling correctly.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for that detailed answer. I will not risk the led and therefore follow your advice .. actually I didn`t see that hint you mentioned before, but just watched the title and voltage details before..
Do you maybe have a better idea, on how to "safely" power the mentioned devices inside a thin case with one single 230v line going to the case itself !?